# PdfBox showing certified by instead of signed by in digital signature

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I have put digital signature via Pdf Box using this [example](https://github.com/xiaojiahuo/pdfbox/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignature.java)

I digitally sign a pdf twice.

- First time it showing : **Certified by My SSL Certificate**
- Second time it showing : **Re.2. Signed by My SSL Certificate**

[image]

It should show first time **Re.1. Signed By My SSL Certificate**

any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this segment from your code:

```
    // Optional: certify 
    if (accessPermissions == 0)
    {
        SigUtils.setMDPPermission(document, signature, 2);
    }
```

That's the part that makes it a certification.